# how to convert system.net.ipaddress to a system.collection arraylist

Tags: vb.net

I have a server with multiple ip addresses. I am using system.net.ipaddress class to get these. Now i want to move these multiple ips to a string array so that I can remove some values if needed. when i try this

```
Private ArrIpAddress As IPAddress()
Private IpAddressList As ArrayList()

IpAddressList = ArrIpAddress
```

I get this error 
Value of type 1 dimensional array of system.net.ipaddress cannot be converted to 1 dimensional array of system.collections.arraylist

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Arrays and ArrayList are two different things and not interchangeable.  you can add the contents to the other though: `IpAddressList.AddRange(ArrIpAddress)`  a `List(of T)` might be better than an ArrayList though

Comment: thanks for update i used addrange to convert arripaddress to array list.